# Whats wrong with TDateTime value

Tags: c++builder, tdbgrid, tdatetime, tfield

I have a TDateTime variable called currMonth. currMonth's value is "6/30/2000 11:59:59 PM".
I need to insert currMonth as default value for a field at TDBGrid called dtBegin.

I try this code :

```
dtBegin->AsDateTime = currMonth;
```

And the compiler is succeed compiling the project, but when I debug it, I get dtBegin value is not "6/30/2000 11:59:59 PM" but { 36738.9999999884 }.

Anyone know whats wrong with this TDateTime object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous replies to [your same question that you posted on the Embarcadero forum](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=83220) at the same time you posted here.

In a nutshell, there is nothing wrong at all.  `TDateTime` is implemented as a `double` internally.  The debug inspector is merely showing you that `double` value as-is, not a formatted date/time string that you are expecting.  This is normal behavior, and your `TDateTime` itself will work fine in your code.  You are using an older version of C++Builder, so you do not have the `TDateTime` debug visualizer that newer versions of C++Builder have for displaying `TDateTime` values nicer, that's all.

If you need to see the `TDateTime` value in a formatted manner inside the debugger, you will have to define an entry in the Watch List that calls the RTL's `DateTimeToStr()` function, or the `TDateTime::FormatString()` method, and displays the result to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Remy. I'm so understand now.